# How to empty a Vuex store module state object?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

How to empty a Vuex store module state object completely? I know how to delete a single property of state object for e.g `Vue.delete(state.slidesList, 'slide1')` but I want to completely empty the state object (not delete the object itself) *without losing reactivity* on the object itself, when individual properties are deleted (using `Vue.delete`) removes reactive getters and setters, I believe, pls correct if this is wrong.

Does directly setting `state.slideList = {}` empties the object, while still being reactive? if yes then it implies `state.slideList = {fname: 'Appu' }` is a way to overwrite the object without emptying the object (if the goal is to overwrite the object completely with another object, rather than empty and re-write in it).

If not, what is the correct way to overwrite the state object with another new non-empty object.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***`set`** adds a property to a `reactive` object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add
> new properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal
> property additions.* [*doc*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

module.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const initialState = {
 foo: {},
 bar: {},
 // ...
}

const state = {...initialState}

const mutations = { // To reset a state
 RESET_FOO (state) {
  Vue.set(state, 'foo', initialState.foo)
 },

 UPDATE_FOO (state, payload) { // To update the state
  Vue.set(state, 'foo', payload)
 },

 UPDATE_IN_FOO (state, { key, value }) { // To update a key in a state
  Vue.set(state.foo, key, value)
 },

 RESET_MODULE (state) { // To reset the entire module
  Object.assign(state, initialState)
 }
}
```

Comment: @appu please let me know if I missed any relevant case, above, that may be required in your use case. Thanks

Comment: `Object.assign()` copies/overwrites the state properties with/from the ones from initialState. If you miss to declare a property in initialState, it will not get reset in the state and remains like before. Be careful about this.

Answer (score 1):

Vuex has `replaceState` method that replaces store's root state.

Comment: Please could you show this with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutation that resets the state. Then, reset the state with a default value like this:

```
Object.assign(state, newState)
```